# Consul - External service registration with more than 1 service

Tags: api, service, external, consul

I want know if Im doing something wrong or the support for Consul External services is actually kind of limited ( or designed that way maybe).
I cant use ESM because I cannot install anything else, even if in containers :(.

Case:
- I have several hosts where Mysql has at least 4 processes running.
- I installed exporters on those hosts for each mysql process, which are already exposing the metrics for prometheus.
- I want those exporters to be registered in Consul as external services as I cant install the consul agent.

I already checked the Consul documentation and it seems that I cant register an external node with several services, just 1 service per node.

```html
{
  "Node": "ltmysqldb01-1.com",
  "Address": "ltmysqldb01-1.com",
  "NodeMeta": {
    "external-node": "true",
    "external-probe": "true"
  },
  "Service": {
    "ID": "ltmysqldb01-1-node_exporter",
    "Service": "node_exporter", 
    "Port": 9100
  },
  "Checks": [{
    "Name": "http-check",
    "status": "passing",
    "Definition": {
      "http": "ltmysqldb01-1.com",
      "interval": "30s"
    }
  }]
}


curl --request PUT --data @external_mysql_ltmysqldb01-1.json https://consul-instance.com/v1/catalog/register
```

Answer (score 0):

[Multiple services can be easily defined per single node(agent):](https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/services.html#multiple-service-definitions)

You basically setup agent, and configure it with several external services.